# How am I receiving the following output when (incorrectly) dereferencing a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is not so much a question that I need solving, it's more a case of I made a mistake which resulted in weird output, and I'm curious what's going on.

So if point1 is a pointer to the char "var", and point2 is a pointer to the pointer point1, to correctly dereference point2 as follows:

```
cout << **point2 << endl;
```

Which would ouput "y" as expected.

However, if I incorrectly dereference the pointer, as follows:

```
cout << *point2 << endl;
```

Then the output would include any subsequent variables declared after the initial variable var.
For example, in the code below, var2 would also be included, for an ouput of "yn", and further variables such as

```
char var3 = 'a';
char var4 = 'b';
```

Also seem to be included for an ouput of "ynab".
I think I understand *how* it's happening, and outputting the memory addresses of each of the variables through a method such as:

```
cout << (void *) &var <<endl;
```

Which confirms that each variable is adjacent in memory, however I'm unsure *why* it is happening.

**Why does improperly dereferencing a pointer to a pointer seem to return successive variables?**

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char var = 'y';
char var2 = 'n';

//Declare point1 as a pointer to a char
char* point1 = &var;

//Declare point2 as pointer to pointer to char
char** point2 = &point1;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Dereference point1: " << *point1 << endl;

    cout << "Dereference point2: " << **point2 << endl;
    cout << "Bad dereference of point2: " << *point2 << endl;

    cout << "Var: " << var << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, that just means it could work, or it could not work, or your machine could blow up, anything could happen. As you have seen, the variables _happen_ to be memory adjacent in this case, but you can't make any assumptions about that.

Comment: By the way when I run the code, I get `y` twice, I don't get `n` at all.

Comment: @KarlReid whoops I forgot to include the "bad" dereferencing, will update OP in a sec.

Comment: @Potatosaurus  Whay is 'y' outputted in this statement when point1 points to "var" ?:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `*point2` is of type `char *` which is treated as a string. If it's not really a string then you have *undefined behavior* and that's really the end of the story.

In reality what happens is that the output operator `<<` reads consecutive bytes from memory until it hits a zero (the "string terminator"). In your case the compiler have put the storage for the variables next to each other, that's why you see both being output in the "string".

Comment: I'd have to argue that behavior is, in fact, defined.

Comment: @veganaiZe The program goes out of bounds of the single character variable. Going out of bounds is always UB.

Comment: The display of the consecutive characters would happen in every implementation; Undefined behavior would likely produce varying results under various implementations. I think we've landed on the fence with this one, as part of the output is defined and the invisible part is not.

Comment: But it is not REQUIRED to be consecutive. The some of the storage could be on Pluto over a quantum entanglement link, some accessed from Mordor via palantir and the remainder stashed at the bottom of the Mariana Trench and communicated via Aquaman through telepathic fish. So long as it meets the requirements for Automatic and Dynamic storage, C++ will allow the most batsmurf of fantasy.

Comment: @veganaiZe -- unless `var` has the value `'\0'`, `point2` does not point to a nul-terminated array of `char`; treating it as one produces undefined behavior.

Comment: What am I thinking...  I am probably wrong.  Does anyone know where to find how standard C++ assigns pointer values to chars?

Comment: @veganaiZe https://isocpp.org/ Top left corner under the logo you'll find a link to an up-to-date draft of the next C++ standard.

Comment: Sorry, it's too early today...  I finally got the ability to comment after not being able to drop any well-thought knowledge for so long...  Maybe it is still too early.  Back to that little hole for me.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks.  If I can't find it in there I will submit a proposal and attempt to get sequential value pointer assignment (so that I will look like a genius in the future). Truth be told, I am actually an out-of-work C and wanna-be Python programmer (can you tell ;) -- BTW You took my 1st choice for a username!

Comment: @veganaiZe It's undefined behavior because that's what the standard says about out of bounds access. Even if the following variables were guaranteed to be consecutive so as to imply that the out of bounds access would always end up dereferencing those variables, it would *still* be undefined behavior. If the compiler can detect this situation, it is free to do anything. It might assume that your function is unreachable in the name of optimization. Here is [an example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) of undefined behavior fundamentally changing the program.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Can you please site the source of your answer (in the standard itself)?

Comment: @veganaiZe I'm not sure for which part of my answer you want a source. In any case, it's purpose was to explain that undefined behavior can't be circumvented by tightening the underlying representation and layout of objects in memory. Even if you can be certain of how objects would be layed out, you can't rely on safely accessing that representation if it's done through undefined behavior because the compiler may detect the attempt and can rightfully disregard your intentions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I just think we should follow due process and confirm that, regardless of any implementation and hearsay, the standard truly does not define that variables should be handed sequential vector-table values for pointers (internally). Even if an optimizing compiler is allowed to go crazy as soon as it hits a bound, in theory, that optimization could be disabled and there is (until it is shown otherwise in the standard) the possibility that this behavior is defined.  I have yet to be proven wrong and I feel (as much as the next person) that I should be.

Comment: @veganaiZe My comments intended to discuss the nature of undefined behavior and the futility of trying to circumvent it *in general*, not specifically for your case. I used this question's subject as an example, assuming that it is in fact undefined behavior. If it happens that it *isn't* undefined behavior, I've chosen a poor example but the arguments message unchanged. That said, I've looked into finding a citation in the standard regarding local variable layout but I couldn't come up with one. Keep in mind that behavior is implicitly undefined unless otherwise defined by the standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147862/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-veganaize).

Comment: You may want to consider posting a question on the subject, with the language lawyer tag. Answers with that tag are expected to be pedantic and to cite reliable sources.

Answer (score 3):

C++ thinks that the *pointer to char* is the beginning of a **string**.  So it tries to continue printing until it finds a `NULL` value.